# Extracting simplified graph in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have a network that looks like this

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)

data("kite")
plot(kite)
```

[image: The graph I am working with]

I run a community detection and the result looks like this

```
community <- cluster_fast_greedy(kite)
plot(community,kite)
```

[image: The result of the community detection mapped on the network]

Now I want to extract a network based on the communities. The edge weight should be the number of ties between communities (how strong are communities connected to each other), the vertex attribute should be the number of nodes in the community (called numnodes).

```
d <- data.frame(E=c(1, 2, 3),
                A=c(2, 3, 1))
g2 <- graph_from_data_frame(d, directed = F)
E(g2)$weight <- c(5, 1, 1)
V(g2)$numnodes <- c(4,3,3)

plot.igraph(g2,vertex.label=V(g2)$name, edge.color="black",edge.width=E(g2)$weight,vertex.size=V(g2)$numnodes)
```

The graph should look like this
[image: Final product]
One node is larger than the others, one edge has a lot of weight in comparison to the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `igraph` doesn't have method to count edges connecting groups of vertices. Therefore to count the edges connecting communities you need to iterate over each pairs of communities. To count the members for each community, you can use the `sizes` method.

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)

data("kite")
plot(kite)

community <- cluster_fast_greedy(kite)
plot(community,kite)

cedges <- NULL

for(i in seq(1,max(community$membership) - 1)){
    for(j in seq(i + 1, max(community$membership))){
        imembers <- which(community$membership == i)
        jmembers <- which(community$membership == j)
        weight <- sum(
            mapply(function(v1) mapply(
                function(v2) are.connected(kite, v1, v2),
                jmembers),
            imembers)
        )
        cedges <- rbind(cedges, c(i, j, weight))
    }
}

cedges <- as.data.frame(cedges)
names(cedges)[3] <- 'weight'
cgraph <- graph_from_data_frame(cedges, directed = FALSE)

V(cgraph)$numnodes <- sizes(community)

plot.igraph(cgraph,
    vertex.label = V(cgraph)$name,
    edge.color = "black",
    edge.width = E(cgraph)$weight,
    vertex.size = V(cgraph)$numnodes)
```